# Copying Dynamic Range Into New Workbooks, Adding Header, And Saving New Workbooks To Local Directory Before Closing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master workbook with one sheet that I need to be broken into many workbooks that each have a single worksheet.

These newly created workbooks will be created when rows in the "Master" worksheet have the same content in column B.

I need these workbooks to be saved to the same specific local directory with the file name being the content of column B & ".csv" to make the file a CSV file rather than an XLSX file.

Here is what I have so far (a lot of this came from another upvoted thread on this site with a few tweaks by me).

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim Master As Workbook
    Set Master = Workbooks("Master").Worksheets("Master") 'This declares the target worksheet.

    last = 1
    For i = 1 To 2000 'This defines the amount of rows
        If Range("B" & i) <> Range("B" & (i + 1)) Then
            Range("A" & last & ":F" & i).Copy 
            Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
            NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("A1").Value = "Header1"
            Range("B1").Value = "Header2"
            Range("C1").Value = "Header3"
            Range("D1").Value = "Header4"
            Range("E1").Value = "Header5"
            Range("F1").Value = "Header6"

            last = i + 1
            Master.Activate
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code will create hundreds, if not thousands, of workbooks with single worksheets from the "Master" Workbook.

I'm having a couple issues here:

1. This code:

   ```
   Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Range("A1").Value = "Header1"
   Range("B1").Value = "Header2"
   Range("C1").Value = "Header3"
   Range("D1").Value = "Header4"
   Range("E1").Value = "Header5"
   Range("F1").Value = "Header6"
   ```

   appears to be adding the header row correctly but it seems to be copying the entire contents of the spreadsheet and pasting it at the *next available row*.  It then overwrites the contents of row 1.

   Example: The macro pulls the following rows to a new workbook:

   ```
   Bat 
   Bat
   Bat
   ```

   When the above section of code runs, the final product is:

   ```
   Header
   Bat
   Bat
   Bat
   Bat
   Bat
   ```

   It appears to be replicating the content and then pasting over row 1.
2. The second issue, as alluded to earlier, is that the newly created workbooks/worksheets will not be automatically saved (CSV) and closed, and I will need to go in and close/save them each myself.

   They seem to be being created correctly (with the exception of the issue in problem #1).  They are simply left open and I need to name and save all of them.  Since I am sure there will be a great many of the newly created workbooks, this lack of functionality will make my life very difficult ...

---

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I am fairly new to this, but am picking it up pretty quickly.

My apologies for the long post, I wanted to be as clear as I could as to not waste the readers time.

Comment: Also John, can I see few screenshots of what your master file looks like and what one of the output should look like? I like testing my code before posting an answer.

Comment: @Peh Thank you!  That fixes problem #1.  I'm going to edit the post to reflect your correction.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnSmith See my answer below for second solution. And please don't remove parts of your questions. Other users are using this site for learning or might have similar issues. If you remove parts of your question it isn't useful for other people anymore.

Comment: @Peh I reverted the post format back to its original form.  It makes sense to leave it as it was (per your guidance).  I'm really new to the site, so I am still learning the etiquette.

Comment: @JohnSmith No worries that's why I explained it.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  Thank you for looking into this for me and asking for more information.  I got this to work with Peh's solution.  Best regards.

Comment: Glad it got sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you are still in CopyMode from `Range("A" & last & ":F" & i).Copy` the `.Insert` will insert the copied rows again. Therefore put a `Application.CutCopyMode = False` right before `Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert` to stop inserting copied rows again.
2. You need [`Workbook.SaveAs Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) and [`Workbook.Close Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx) to save and close the workbooks.

   ```
   NewBook.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)
   NewBook.Close(SaveChanges, Filename, RouteWorkbook)
   ```

   eg. This should work:

   ```
   NewBook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Temp\MyFileName.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
   NewBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
   ```
3. You should specify any `Rows()` and `Range()` with a worksheet like `Master.Rows()` or `NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range()` so that is clear in which workbook\worksheet the range/row is. Then you don't need `Master.Activate`

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  Is there anyway to have the file names populate dynamically based on the content of the file (e.g. Range("B2") = "String" therefore NewBook.SaveAs(FileName:="C:\Temp\String", FileFormat:=xlCSV)?

Comment: Of course you just need to append it `NewBook.SaveAs(FileName:="C:\Temp\" & Range("B2"), FileFormat:=xlCSV)` but make sure that … (1) you specify the sheet for  that range eg `Master.Range("B2")` and (2) that B2 is not empty and a valid file name (not containing invalid characters) otherwise save will fail.

Comment: Thanks again.  That is exactly what I need.  One other issue though.  I'm getting the message "Compile Error: Expected: =".  Maybe I'm putting the code in the wrong spot?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm...That worked, but now I am having another issue that may be unrelated.  I am getting "Run-time error '1004':   Cannot access read-only document "Testfile.csv'." when I try to save to C:\Test.   I read in another forum that the error has something to do with root access on my computer.  When I try to run the code on the same section of the worksheet and save to D:\Test again, it says there is a file there and I need to overwrite.  It seems to go through when I save to D:\Test, with there is nothing in the folder.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  I was not adding a '\' after the folder I wanted to put the files into.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: ++ For following it through :)

Answer (score 0):

What think about this code.

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim Master As Workbook
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim strFile As String

    Set Master = Workbooks("Master").Worksheets("Master") 'This declares the target worksheet.

    last = 1
    For i = 1 To 2000 'This defines the amount of rows
        If Range("B" & i) <> Range("B" & i + 1) Then
            strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("b" & i) & ".csv"
            TransToCSV strFile, Range("A" & last & ":F" & i)
            last = i + 1

        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub TransToCSV(myfile As String, rng As Range)

    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strTxt As String, strHeader As String
    strHeader = "Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6" & vbCrLf
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)

                vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
            vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strTxt = strHeader & Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```