# How to split different fixed rows into different formats?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Sample Data: goo.gl/akWozD (Assume 1 million rows with 8 columns)

How to edit the VBA codes below to churn out different file format (CSV and Excel) with different fixed rows? For example: the `InputBox` will ask for `CSV` fixed rows size and also `Excel` fixed rows size simultaneously.

The desired output would be `CSV 1, CSV 2, CSV 3, etc` and `Excel 1, Excel 2, Excel 3, etc` where `CSV` has X fixed rows and `Excel` has Y fixed rows, in the same folder. The original workbook will not be changed/modified. `X` and `Y` will be asked when Macro is run.

Thank you.

```
Public Sub SplitFixedRows()
  Dim wbOrig As Workbook
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
  Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
  Dim RangeToCopy As Range
  Dim RangeOfHeader As Range
  Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
  Dim RowsInFile

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  RowsInFile = InputBox("Please enter data size +1 header (Example: 11, 101, 501): ")

  Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ThisSheet = wbOrig.ActiveSheet
  NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  WorkbookCounter = 1

  Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))
  For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
    RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

    wb.SaveAs wbOrig.Path & "\Data " & WorkbookCounter
    wb.Close

    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
  Next p

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: confer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582005/copying-dynamic-range-into-new-workbooks-adding-header-and-saving-new-workbook/44584306#44584306)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you only lack producing `CSV` file. This can be done in in following steps:

```
Dim FSO, wfile As Object
Dim content As String
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wfile = FSO.OpenTextFile("path to the file", 2) 'connection for writing

'here you prepare whole content of the file

wfile.Write content
wfile.Close
```

In order to prepare the `content` of the file, you just append to it values in consecutive cells separated by comma (or whatever you want). To  do that, you just need to loop through the range :)