# Converting excel files to UTF-8 .TSV

Tags: vba, csv, excel-2010

Every week i have to convert 25 or more excel files to **UTF-8 .tsv files**. As of now im doing it using **Editplus** application manually.

I was searching in google and other sites where im getting UTF-8 **.csv** conversion only.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582005/copying-dynamic-range-into-new-workbooks-adding-header-and-saving-new-workbook/44584306#44584306).  This is for csv file. `join( vr, vbTab)` This can create tab-separated files.

Comment: Thank you! i have 104 header files here i need to all 104 headers..?? should i apply the above change here   vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")??

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myfile As String
    
    'If you need a loop, start here
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rng = Ws.UsedRange
    myfile = "testTab.txt"
    
    TransToTab myfile, rng
    'Loop end
End Sub
Sub TransToTab(myfile As String, rng As Range)

    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strTxt As String, strHeader As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
                vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
            vTxt(n) = Join(vR, vbTab)
    Next i
    strTxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! myfile = "testTab.txt" just need clarification on this line.. Why we are hard coding name in .txt? I want to create .tsv files from excel in UTF-8 format.
I tried the above code it was running but unable to get or find any result!!!!

Comment: @Linga,   You can rename it like this(`myfile = "testTab.tsv"`). Just change it to whatever name you want.And add the file path.

Comment: Oh ok where to add the path?

Comment: @Linga,  `myfile = path & \" &   "testTab.txt"`

Comment: Amazing its is working fine! But instead of UTF-8 file getting saved in UTF-8+BOM format. Can it be done?

Comment: Hi getting type mismatch error# 13 in line vR(j) = vDB(i, j)  why im getting it?